# How do I find the best parameter to fit my data if the model is a interpolating function?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

Hi I have a question regarding to find the best parameters for my model to fit my data. 
I have 3 ordinary equation, and I now just picked some parameters (`k1 = 7.32*10^-5; k2 = 8.09*10^-9`) for my ODE.

Defined all the constant values:

```
k1 = 7.32*10^-5;
k2 = 8.09*10^-9;
Da = 1.33*10 - 4;
Nd0 = 0.001;
HR0 = 0.2;
H0908 = 0.004;
x0 = 0.007;
```

And define the 3 ODE equations:

```
Equation1908 = {Nd0*
     Caf908'[t] == -k1*(Nd0*HR0)/H0908*Caf908[t]*Cbf908[t]/Hf908[t] + 
     k2*(0.2 - 3*HR0*Cbf908[t]),
   HR0*Cbf908'[t] == -3*k1*(Nd0*HR0)/H0908*Caf908[t]*
      Cbf908[t]/Hf908[t] + 3*k2*(0.2 - 3*HR0*Cbf908[t]),
   H0908*Hf908'[t] == 
    3*k1*(Nd0*HR0)/H0908*Caf908[t]*Cbf908[t]/Hf908[t] - 
     3*k2*(0.2 - 3*HR0*Cbf908[t]),
   Caf908[0] == 1, Cbf908[0] == 1, Hf908[0] == 1};
```

Using `NDSolve`:

```
BC1908 = NDSolve[
  Equation1908, {Caf908[t], Cbf908[t], Hf908[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}]
```

At the end, I obtained 3 interpolating function, for `Caf908[t]`, `Cbf908[t]`, and `Hf908[t]`... I used the solution (`Caf908[t]`)  to fit my data. X-axis (`tfexp0908`) versus y-axis (`fexp0908`):

```
fexp0908 = .001*{1.009790523`, 0.898335138`, 0.878948419`, 
    0.830114856`, 0.767123385`, 0.732170062`, 0.672106602`, 
    0.637589428`, 0.59141947`, 0.523944512`, 0.554584169`, 
    0.451444203`, 0.396545111`, 0.444125908`, 0.352355452`, 
    0.272913948`, 0.33877861`, 0.287900412`, 0.276936425`};
tfexp0908 = {0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 180, 210, 
   245, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390};
```

And I obtained a good fit. But I would like to know how I can use *Mathematica* to obtain the best parameter, `k1` & `k2`, for my model (`Caf908[t]`) and get the best fit to my data. Thank you!

Comment: its doable in principle but right now your set of equations does not seem to integrate properly. You forgot to give k1 a value

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry that I forgot to include a value for k1. K1& k2 values are:k1 = 7.32*10^-5;
k2 = 8.09*10^-9;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clear the `k1` and `k2` variables and put in `kk1` and `kk2` the corresponding values

```
Clear[k1, k2];
kk1 = 7.32*10^-5;
kk2 = 8.09*10^-9;
```

Now define a set of equations to solve depending on `k1,k2`

```
Equation[k1_?NumberQ,k2__?NumberQ] = {Nd0*
     Caf908'[t] == -k1*(Nd0*HR0)/H0908*Caf908[t]*Cbf908[t]/Hf908[t] + 
     k2*(0.2 - 3*HR0*Cbf908[t]), 
     HR0*Cbf908'[t] == -3*k1*(Nd0*HR0)/H0908*Caf908[t]*
      Cbf908[t]/Hf908[t] + 3*k2*(0.2 - 3*HR0*Cbf908[t]), 
     H0908*Hf908'[t] == 
      3*k1*(Nd0*HR0)/H0908*Caf908[t]*Cbf908[t]/Hf908[t] - 
      3*k2*(0.2 - 3*HR0*Cbf908[t]), Caf908[0] == 1, Cbf908[0] == 1, 
   Hf908[0] == 1};
```

Now let us define a $\chi^2$ function

```
Clear[chi2];
chi2[k1_?NumberQ, k2_?NumberQ] :=
 (sol = 
   Caf908 /. NDSolve[
      Equation[k1, k2], {Caf908, Cbf908, Hf908}, {t, 0, 1000}] // 
    First;
  (sol /@ tfexp0908) - fexp0908 // #.# &
  )
```

and let's sample this function around what is supposedly the correct value

```
Table[chi2[kk1*i, kk2*j], {i, 0.1, 2.1, 0.1}, {j, 0.1, 5.1, 
   0.2}] // ListContourPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems to suggest i) the guess is not so good ii) somehow the $\chi^2$ does not depend on
k2

Finding the right range of values for `kk1` and `kk2`
and sorting out why the $\chi^2$ does not depend on `k1` is beyond a *Mathematica* question?

Note that one could use in principle `NMinimize` to find the solution more efficiently than via sampling the likelihood function, but before these points are addressed there's no point.

**EDIT**

I believe you should remove the `0.01*` in front of `fexp0908`

```
Clear[chi2];
chi2[k1_?NumberQ, k2_?NumberQ, 
  debug_: False] := (sol = 
   Caf908 /. 
     NDSolve[Equation[k1, k2], {Caf908, Cbf908, Hf908}, {t, 0, 
       1000}] // First;
  If[debug, {(sol /@ tfexp0908), fexp0908} // ListLinePlot // Print];
  (sol /@ tfexp0908) - fexp0908 // #.# &)
```

because without it I get

```
 Table[{i*kk1,chi2[kk1*i, kk2*j]},{i, 0.9, 2.3, 0.1},
    {j, 0.1, 5.1, 0.2}]//Transpose//ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and Indeed  the fit seems okish:

```
 chi2[kk1*1.3, kk2, True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the minimization

```
NMinimize[{chi2[k1, k2], k1 > 0, k2 > 0}, {k1, k2}]

(* {0.0339566,{k1->0.000110757,k2->0.} *)
```

yields a poorer fit but hasn't converged.

It seems your set of data poorly constrains `k2`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Chris. Do you know if there is anyway I can find k1&k2 if the values are incorrect? I just started learning mathematica, and know there are findfit and fit. But I must have a function in order to use these two method, and I only have interpolating function from NDSolve. Could you show me how to use NMinimize? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris, the problem is for solving chemical reaction, and k1&k2 are the reaction constants of forward and reverse reactions. I'm still having some problems though. When I use k1&k2 (k1->15.3735,k2->2.45184*10^-9) obtained from NMinimize to fit my data, it gave me a very bad fit, while the previous values (k1 = 7.32*10^-5; k2 = 8.09*10^-9) fits better still. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, Chris! I finally solved the problem after fixing some values and my equations!! I'll let you know if I have more questions!

Comment: @chris What is the `//#.#&` at the end of the chi2 function?

Comment: NVM. I just realized it's the square of the residuals between what's predicted by the interpolation and the actual data.

Comment: `x//#.#&` is the same as `x.x` or `#.#& @ x`  Its sort of polish inverse notation in mathematica if you wish. I find it useful because it reflects the order in which you do things.